# Dismiss keyboard through return key with swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, xcode6, dismiss

I am a beginner programmer working with Swift. I have been working on a to-do list application. I am trying to dismiss a keyboard through the return key. I have tried the 'self.view.endEditing(true)' and the 'resignFirstResponder()' methods, but neither of them are working. Here is my code: (I am using a tab-application)

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var text: UITextField!

@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    toDoList.append(text.text)

    text.text = ""

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.view.endEditing(true) // This works fine here

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.view.endEditing(true) // This is not working...
    return true

}
}
```

At the last function, I have also tried using the following:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    text.resignFirstResponder() // This is not working...
    return true

}
```

But for some reason, neither one is working as I want it to. When I use it in the 'touchesBegan' method, it works fine. Could you please show me what error I am making in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the delegate of your UITextField?

Comment: You aren't overriding the textField... Function. I'm betting that's your problem.

Comment: Yes. That was what I was doing wrong. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the delegate. Add a didSet to the text outlet. Like this.

```
    @IBOutlet var text: UITextField! {
      didSet {
       text.delegate = self
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `resignFirstResponder()` method is the correct one. And by using `textField.resignFirstResponder()` inside of the `textFieldShouldReturn()` method it works with every text field.

so thats it:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: That is what I had. It only works if you add the delegate to the text field.