# Dismissing the keyboard when a button is pressed, programmatically with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I dismiss the keyboard when a button is pressed, programmatically with swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756196/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-when-user-tap-other-area-outside-textfield in place of other area call it on button click

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It all depends on what triggered the keyboard to appear in the first place. If you have a `UITextField` on your page that brought it up, you can call `textField.resignFirstResponder()` to hide the keyboard again.

If you used some other object to bring up the keyboard, simply take the reference of whatever you used and call `resignFirstResponder()` on that object.

**Example:**

Lets say you are using a button `button1` to close the keyboard, and you have a `textField1` that is triggering the keyboard.

```
button1.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "buttonTapped"))
```

Then in your `buttonTappedFunction`

```
func buttonTapped(){
  textField1.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 31):

There is also the so called "big hammer".

Just call `self.view.endEditing(true)`

The documentation states the following for this method:

> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the
>   first responder status.

Answer (score 2):

you have to call `resignFirstResponder` on currently active UI Element (most likely, `UITextField`).

Comment: `UITextFiled` should be `UITextField` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the UITextfield delegate programmatically swift 2.2
Add UITextFieldDelegate in your class.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31689406/5576747