# How can I prevent UISearchController dismiss when cancel button pressed?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to just hide keyboard when user first press cancel button.
Just likes AppStore.app

I use UISearchController like that:

```
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

============== Update ==============
This Cancel button is hosted by UISearchController.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismissing the keyboard when a button is pressed, programmatically with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952064/dismissing-the-keyboard-when-a-button-is-pressed-programmatically-with-swift)

Answer (score 1):

If you did search bar programmatically, you can add extension on your ViewController or else just use function call as below.

```
 extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
     func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         if let text = searchBar.text {
             self.filterContent(text: text)
             searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
         }
     }
 }
```